# Fill data into other blank cells within predefined group of data with data from that defined group

Tags: excel-formula

I am developing some data sheet to check process control limits. I've could develop the system as required. But I like to increase the performance in there. Part of the data sheet that I've developed will described below.

[image: Base Raw Data]
[image]

LSL & USL Limits are as mention in above the table for ID. First I've extract the data into **Help Col 01(Col V)** which are within limits using below formula.

```
=IF(AND(U15>=950,U15<=1150),U15,"")
```

After then I've inserted

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($V$15:$V$30,SMALL(IF($V$15:$V$30<>"",ROW($V$15:$V$30)-ROW($V$15)+1),T15)),"")
```

formula into **Help Col 02(Col W)**, I've removed blank cells. Next task was to add filtered Help Col 2 data into each cell into **Final data list** column according to the group. Groups are described here.
Group 1 = 1-4,Group 2 = 5-8,Group 3 = 9-12,Group 4 = 13-16,
I could approached that task using below formula.

```
=INDEX($W$15:$W$30,MATCH(INT(T15/4.25)+1,$T$15:$T$30,0))
```

My problem is, not possible to merge these formula together due to second formula. If anybody have an idea to merge 1st & 2nd formula into 3rd formula. Any answers are welcome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `V4`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(AGGREGATE(14,6,U$4:U$99/(U$4:U$99<>"")/(U$4:U$99>=V$1)/(U$4:$U99<=V$2),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIFS(U:U,">="&V$1,U:U,"<="&V$2)))),INT((ROW(A1)-1)/4)+1),"")
```

Or, this shorter :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(AGGREGATE(14,6,U$4:U$99/(U$4:U$99<>"")/(U$4:U$99>=V$1)/(U$4:$U99<=V$2),ROW($1:$99)),INT((ROW(A1)-1)/4)+1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This is great. But not fully satisfied my expectation. I've updated the question above with other image. What could you do to fill the data like image in above?

Comment: It is the forum rule : " Don't changed your original specification", You could open a new thread of your 2nd new question/specification, I reject in giving you further help

Comment: Sorry bosco_yip, i did not mean to change the original, I was looking for upgrade of the original question. Thank you for your support anyway.